# How to install Windows service to another system?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, windows

I have developed a Windows service project and have installed it on my local machine and it works just fine as expected.

[image]

Above mentioned files are generated out of Windows service setup. I have an app config file which has DB connection strings.

Now how can I install this service on another machine with app config?

Comment: Copy your assembly and your configuration file to the target system. And use installutil to install the service.

Comment: Do I need to copy all the above mentioned files along with app config file?

Comment: I assume all other dependencies are installed on the target machine. Then "FileMonitorService.exe" and "FileMonitorService.exe.config" from your directory should be sufficient. "FileMonitorService.exe.config" corresponds to your app.config file after building the project.

Comment: @MarcoLaser - That helped! Thank you Marco.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Copy the executable and config files (in your case `FileMonitorService.exe` and `FileMonitorService.exe.config`) on the target machine. 
   In case you need to run remote debugging please remember to also copy `FileMonitorService.pdb` file.
2. Install your service using `InstallUtil.exe`. You must use the `InstallUtil.exe` of the framework version you used to develop your service. For example if your service has been developed with .net 4.x you must use the `InstallUtil.exe` file in the following folder:

   ```
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
   ```

   To install the service open a command prompt on the target machine, move to the location where you copied your files and launch the following command:

   ```
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe FileMonitorService.exe
   ```

More information on Windows service installation can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/sd8zc8ha(v=vs.110).aspx).